# Why is my Squarespace code injection area blank?

Tags: mapbox, squarespace

I inserted an iframe with 'code injection', saved the code and logged out of admin panel, but the result is an intermittent blank frame (attached). I even use the ?logout=true suffix to ensure I am logged out of admin.How do I correct this? I am new to Squarespace.

iframe code:

```
<div id"my-iframe" style="text-align:center;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;overflow:auto /* This needs to be inline for iOS */"><iframe src="http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/Catskill/map2/"></iframe></div>
```

*blank code inject*

[image: blank code inject]

Comment: As a side note, I wouldn't use this method to add Mapbox to your Squarespace website. Mapbox works beautifully by using their JavaScript API, and managing the data in Squarespace as a collection. This way your site has a clean integration and you can manage the data all from within Squarespace. If you want to reword your question a bit I can give you the steps to setting up Mapbox the right way within Squarespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's correct some of the small issues first. Then either you'll have an answer or you'll have a better environment within which to discover the core issue.

1. I'd recommend using a [code block](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167-Using-the-Code-Block) instead of code injection.
2. You're missing an equals sign in your code. It should be `id="my-iframe"`
3. Be sure that, in addition to being logged out, that you are viewing
   the site using the 'http://' protocol and not 'https://'. Your
   iframe may not work properly over https.

Taking these three points into account and adding some of my own CSS to make the map bigger, you can see a working example in a fresh [Squarespace site here](http://brandon-pafx.squarespace.com/about). Note that this link may stop working soon since it's a trial account and I will probably delete it in a week or so. Here is the code I used within a code block:

```
<div id="my-iframe" style="text-align:center;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;overflow:auto /* This needs to be inline for iOS */"><iframe style="width:100%; height:500px;" src="http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/Catskill/map2/"></iframe></div>
```

Finally, note that the map application you are embedding via iframe is responsive, and turns into a list of locations (instead of a map) at widths less than 768px. So don't be thrown off by that.